# Display tooltip on mouseover in the Highchart Stack Column Total

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was looking at this highchart stacked column - [Highchart Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/)
and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a tooltip when you mouse over the total stacked label.

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
       fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
}
```

I wanted to achieve something like this - [See Image here](http://ctrlv.in/628068).

> Note: I wanted to have a tooltip on mouseover the Total Stacked Label not on the column series.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin which allows to cache events on stackLabels.

Comment: I want to have mouse over tooltip on stackLabels too, but custom-events do not support events on stackLabels. There are events supported for many other elements, but I believe those elements already support tooltips.